# Сравнить набор чисел в двух файлах си

Tags: c, файлы

Создать файлы А,В,С. В файлы А и В пользователь заносит числа. В файл С занести все числа с А, которые больше по модулю, чем сооответсвующие из В.
Код позволяет ввести числа в А и В. Не могу их сравнить. Проблема в сканировании данных из файловю Заранее спасибо

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
int main(){
 setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");
 FILE *f1;
 FILE *f2;
 
 float num1;
 float num2;
 int i,n;
 if ((f1=fopen("A.txt", "w+"))==NULL){
printf("\n Невозможно открыть файл для записи");
return 1;
 }
 printf("\n Определите колличество чисел : ");
 scanf("%d", &n);
 printf("\n Введите числа в файл А->");
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
 

scanf("%f", &num1);
fprintf(f1, "%9.2f", num1);
 }
 puts("Файл записан-> A.txt");
 
  if ((f2=fopen("B.txt", "w+"))==NULL){
printf("\n Невозможно открыть файл для записи");
return 1;
 }

 for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
 
printf("\n Введите числа в файл В->");
scanf("%f", &num2);
fprintf(f2, "%9.2f", num2);
 }
 puts("Файл записан-> B.txt");
 float arr1[n];
 float arr2[n];
 f1=fopen("A.txt", "r");
 f2=fopen("B.txt", "r");
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     fscanf(f1, "%f", arr1[i]);
     
     fscanf(f2, "%f", arr2[i]);
  
     
 }
 printf("\n");
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     printf("%f", arr1);
     printf("%f", arr2);
 }
 
 
 
 fclose(f1);
 fclose(f2);
 return 0;}
```

Comment: Почему вы не можете сравнить числа? Что вы попробовали сделать? Что не получилось?

Comment: Проблемы с записью чисел из файлов в масивы, для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Добавьте код в котором вы записываете числа из файлов в массивы и поясните что именно в нем не работает.

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, добавила

Comment: Компилятор выдаёт какие-нибудь предупреждения на строку `fscanf(f1, "%f", arr1[i]);` ?

Comment: нет, все компилируеться и предуприждений нет

Comment: фалы не записываются потому-что вы не сделали `fclose`. и потом вы быстро открываете пустые файлы для чтения.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Не будет толку, оба `fscanf` испорчены. Компилятор орёт как оглашенный. Пользователь - "всё компилируется".

Comment: ну это уже мелочи, что там амперсанты поставить @Stanislav Volodarskiy

Comment: А в конце ещё ничего не будет напечатано: `printf("%f", arr1);`.